# Разделить значение в 1 ячейки на 3 ячейки в Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office

Подскажите, как в Excel разделить строку из одной ячейки на несколько ячеек?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е нужно каждое имя девайса записать в соответсвутющий столбик. Обратите внимание, что во второй строке порядок разный.

Можно ли это сделать с помощью одних только формул?

Если нет, то как это сделать через VBA функцию?

Comment: Есть библиотеки для *Python* с помощью которых можно работать с *Excel* файлами: https://habrahabr.ru/post/232291/

Answer (score 2):

Через VBA. Есть очень хорошая функция [Split](http://vba-help.ru/vbahelp/Function/text/Split/).
Сначала строку делим по ; а затем каждую по :.
Пишем в ячейку через Range и Value.

Answer (score 1):

Через формулы могу предложить такой вариант:

```
=ПСТР($A3;ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ(B$1;":");$A3;ПОИСК(B$1;$A3))+ДЛСТР(B$1)+1;ПОИСК(";";$A3;ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ(B$1;":");$A3))-ПОИСК(":";$A3;ПОИСК(СЦЕПИТЬ(B$1;":");$A3))-1)
```

Где `$A2` - это ячейка со строкой исходных данных, а `B$1` - заголовок `Device 1`.
В первом случае столбец, а во втором строка сделаны абсолютными ссылками, чтобы формулу можно было скопировать в другое место, и при этом она бы продолжала ссылаться на правильные ячейки.

Только важное замечание, строка исходных данных должна обязательно заканчиваться на `;`, т.к. этот знак считается флагом окончания значения.

Answer (score 1):

Столбец *А* - исходные данные, строка *2* - "шапка таблицы"

```
=ЛЕВБ(ПСТР($A3&";";ПОИСК(B$2;$A3)+ДЛСТР(B$2)+1;20);ПОИСК(";";ПСТР($A3&";";ПОИСК(B$2;$A3)+ДЛСТР(B$2)+1;20))-1)
```

В формуле *A3&";"* - дополнение строки можно убрать, если последний символ в исходных данных всегда точка с запятой.

Вторая формула и без сцепки нечувствительна к отсутствию последнего символа.

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ЛЕВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПСТР($A3;ПОИСК(B$2;$A3)+ДЛСТР(B$2)+1;20);";";ПОВТОР(" ";50));50))
```

---

Решение с помощью функции пользователя (*UDF*) с использованием функции *ПОИСК*

```
Function FindName(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
Dim j As Long
    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(r2.Value, r1.Value)
    FindName = Split(Mid$(r1.Value, j + Len(r2.Value) + 1), ";")(0)
End Function
```

Вариант без использования функций листа:

```
Function FindName(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    FindName = Split(Split(r1.Value, r2.Value & ":")(1), ";")(0)
End Function
```

Функцию разместить в общем модуле.

В ячейку *В3* вписать формулу:

```
=FindName($A3;B$2)
```

Размножить на нужный диапазон

Недостаток *UDF* - волатитьность (пересчитываются при любых изменениях на листе)